# Python3 key error on keys that exist?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key, keyerror

I get a `KeyError: 'date/homeTeam/awayTeam'` on a list of objects that are structured like this:

```
{
  '_id': {
    '$oid': '5b68f822cf785e0013cb7702'
  },
  'date': 'Sun, 05 Aug 2018 23:00:00 GMT',
  'homeTeam': 'Stone Cold Killers',
  'awayTeam': 'Danglers'
}
```

Though if I try to get the `id` it works. This is what I am using to get the data:

```
json.loads(dumps(match))['homeTeam']
```

Traceback: https://pastebin.com/Utykdxkh

Comment: Could you share the full error traceback?  I don't think that line is the one responsible for that error message.

Comment: Sure I updated with a pastebin of it wasnt sure how to make it formatted on here

Comment: You should rework your code a bit so that you print the dictionary before doing the key lookup.  Then the last dictionary it prints will be the one that's failing.

Comment: @amedeiros what is output of `json.loads(dumps(match))`. Can you print it and add it to the question?

Comment: I think I found the issue thanks to Patrick. I forgot that one of the records has DATE instead of date which is what is causing the issue I am assuming